# Switch case statement - Generic associated type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums

I am trying to associate a generic type with a switch case statement but I am getting a compile time error.

```
enum TextEditEvent{
case editingBegin(UITextField)
case editingEnd(UITextField, UITextField?)
case textChanged<T>(String?, UILabel?, T, String) where T:Object, T:Updatable
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `enum` itself has to be declared generic, not its case and you cannot use a where clause in the `case` declaration, you need to specify the generic type constraints on the associated value.

```
enum TextEditEvent<T>{
    case editingBegin(UITextField)
    case editingEnd(UITextField, UITextField?)
    case textChanged(String?, UILabel?, T:Object, Updateable, String)
}
```

Or if you want `T` to have those type constraints in the whole `enum`, not only for the `textChanged` case, you can declare the `enum` like this:

```
enum TextEditEvent<T: Object, Updateable>{
    case editingBegin(UITextField)
    case editingEnd(UITextField, UITextField?)
    case textChanged(String?, UILabel?, T, String)
}
```